# my css and javascript files do not load and do not work?

Tags: javascript, theming, files

my uploaded drupal7 website worked correctly for 2 days.but suddenly when i refresh it,every things go wrong.
site loads with no css and no java,and no pictures.
it said that the css (and js) files couldn't be found even though they were very clearly there.and i can open them from cpanel.
i delete all files and my database completely from my host,then i upload all files and database again,but nothing changed.
actually i did this work several times.and nothing changed.
my website on localhost work correctly.
i do not know what is the problem?and how i can fix it?
is the problem from my host?
my website url:www.tehrantoyur.com
please check it,and guide me completly.

Comment: did you check the permission of css/js files?

Comment: oh my god,i give full permision to the css folder and java folder.now it works corectly.thank u so much,so much